# Does it matter which term I pass to d3.selectAll() during a data join, if whatever I append seems to rely solely on the .append() call?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm adding some circles to a d3 chart, and am somewhat confused by the argument passed to `svg.selectAll()`. Here, I run a data join on my data and some circles:

```
svg.selectAll("top")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr({
        "cx": function(d,i){return i*50+50},
        "cy": 60,
        "r": function(d) {return rScale(parseFloat(d.value));},
        "class": "top"
    })
    .style({
        "fill": "CornflowerBlue",
        "stroke": "blue",
        "opacity": 0.8
    });
```

This code seems to be, from what I've played with it, the same as:

```
    svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr({
            "cx": function(d,i){return i*50+50},
            "cy": 60,
            "r": function(d) {return rScale(parseFloat(d.value));},
            "class": "top"
        })
        .style({
            "fill": "CornflowerBlue",
            "stroke": "blue",
            "opacity": 0.8
        });
```

To save you the trouble of hunting down the one difference between the two code blocks, it's `selectAll("top")` vs. `selectAll("circle")`.

Whenever I've gone through examples, I've nearly always seen a match between the selection and the appended element, but this doesn't seem to matter, at least not in the code above when I ran it. At first I thought that maybe you could use something along the lines of a class selection and append elements to it (`svg.selectAll(".top")`), but this doesn't work either. So what exactly is the underlying use for the argument of `d3.selectAll()`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The underlying reason for how enter() works on the initial creation has to do with what is called data-join or the enter-update-exit pattern.  Here's a link:
http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Yes, it does matter -- always select the element you then append.

Longer explanation: The [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_selectAll) is clear on the purpose of the argument:

> Selects all elements that match the specified selector.

The argument you give to `selectAll()` determines what ends up in the selection that you then operate on. For example, if you `d3.selectAll("circle")`, the selection will contain all the `circle` elements on the page. Note that if there are no such elements, the selection will be empty (which is usually the case when you're creating a visualisation initially).

You're correct that in your case it doesn't matter what argument you pass. This is because there are no elements on your page and the selection is empty, regardless of the selector string. It does however matter when there are elements on the page that you may want to update. The contents of a selection determine what D3's data binding does, in particular what data is bound to what element and which elements are determined to be "new" (the enter selection), "updated" (the update selection), and "old" (the exit selection) (more on that in [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/)).

In short, if you're selecting the wrong elements, elements that you expect to be updated won't be and additional elements will appear when they shouldn't. Imaging selecting `top` with some `circle` elements present. The selection will be empty, so additional circles will be added for each datum even though you actually want to update the existing ones.

Ok, so why should you care about this if you only ever want to use the enter selection to append new elements and are never going to update them? First, it makes your code easier to read and understand. Second, and more importantly, it avoids subtle bugs when you (or someone else) later decides that you do want to update existing elements after all.

Edit after comment: If there are multiple sets of the same elements that you need to distinguish, use classes:

```
 d3.selectAll("circle.top").data(top)
   .enter().append("circle").classed("top", true);
 d3.selectAll("circle.bottom").data(bottom)
   .enter().append("circle").classed("bottom", true);
```

Comment: Lars, this is great, thank you! I do have a question, however. I played with this in my code because I have a need to place circles onto the SVG twice; one will be a row at the top, indicating ratio size, and the other will be below. The code above works for me because I'm doubling up; If I selectAll("circle") both times, however, I can't append the second row of circles from that same data. 

In this case, am I still likely to get the subtle errors you mentioned, or is the way I'm doing it the way it should be done as per "best practices"?

Comment: You can use classes for this. I've updated the answer.